# Comparación de variable con constante en java no funciona como debería

Tags: java, condiciones, booleano

**En esta sección de mi codigo no entra en el if hasta cambiar el valor de la boleana "Pregunta"**

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int roundtime = 0, restime = 0, roundnumbers = 0;
String name, respuesta;
boolean preguntas=true;
        
while (preguntas) {
System.out.println("¿Cual es tu nombre?");
            name = sc.next();
            System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");
            System.out.flush();
            System.out.println("Bienvenido " + name + "\n");
            System.out.println("¿Cuantas rondas de estudio quieres hoy?");
            roundnumbers = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");
            System.out.flush();
            System.out.println("Ahora porfavor indica cuanto quieres que duren estas rondas (En minutos)");
            roundtime = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("¿Y cuanto quieres que duren tus descansos? (En minutos)");
            restime = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("¿Toda la información es correcta?");
                respuesta = sc.next();
                preguntas = false;
            if (respuesta=="no") {
                preguntas = true;
                }
```

Alguien sabe porque no le cambia el valor, intenté debugear el código y lo único que noto es que cuando llega a esa zona directamente no ejecuta el código de el if a pesar de que entra en el.

Comment: Todo apunta a que no has compilado el código, y estás ejecutando una versión del fuente antigua

Comment: Pero el codigo funciona como tal, utilizo el JavaSE-16

Comment: Si y no. cunado compilas, generas un fichero .class nuevo. Si no compilas, y sencillamente ejecutas, puede que estés ejecutando una versión que no corresponde con el código que estás viendo en pantalla. Pero da igual, mira mi respuesta abajo. creo que lo tengo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La comparación de strings en java no se hace así:

```
if (respuesta=="no") {
     preguntas = true;
}
```

Ahí lo que estás indicando es que "el objeto respuesta no es el mismo objeto que el objeto "no"". Tu intención es preguntar que **el valor** del objeto respuesta sea el mismo que **el valor** del objeto "no". Para ello debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
if( respuesta.equals( "no" ) ) {
    preguntas = true;
}
```

O mejor aún:

```
if( "no".equals( respuesta ) ) {
   preguntas = true; 
}
```

Ya que así evitas la posibilidad de que respuesta valga nulo que te llevaría a tener que hacer una comprobación extra.

O mejor aún:

```
preguntas = "no".equals( respuesta );
```

Es decir, "el resultado de comparar "no" con "respuesta" se lo asignas directamente a la variable preguntas. ¿que es cierto? preguntas valdrá true. ¿que es falso? preguntas valdra false. Y tan felices.

Comment: Pero porqué preguntas pilla un true o false de una string?

Comment: no funciona así: preguntas pilla **el resultado de evaluar "no".equals( respuesta ). El resultado de esa expresión es por narices, un booleano: y es por narices un booleano primero porque equals() dice que devuelve un booleano. Y segundo porque si no, no podría ejecutarse en un if....

Comment: Muchas gracias, me has aclarado muchas cosas!

Comment: me das un +1 a la respuesta?

Comment: Ya se lo he dado pero no sale porque soy un usuario nuevo